# Oracle PLSQL - Multiple LIKE criteria with wildcard characters

Tags: oracle, full-text-search, query-optimization, sql-like

I have a fairly complex data table, but I have cut it down for an easier explanation of what I am trying to accomplish. The goal of the query is to return the ID_NUMBER and TEXT_FIELD where the record contains "John" and "Jane" anywhere in the field, regardless of position or order.

```
ID_Number   Text_Field
1000        John Doe
2000        Jane Doe
3000        John and Jane Doe
4000        Doe John Jane
```

I can easily query to find all of the text fields where "John" is listed by using **LIKE '%JOHN%'**, and I can also query to look for "John" or "Jane" in any part of the text field using **LIKE '%JOHN%' AND LIKE '%JANE%'** but the query seems to take an extremely long time to process.

Is there a more optimal way to write this logic in the WHERE statement?

Comment: Using a LIKE operation with a wildcard at each end is always a full table scan. A more performative approach is to use Oracle Text, which allows us to create special indexes optimized for searching words in free text. It does require a DBA to install some additional libraries and make grants. [Find out more](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CCAPP/toc.htm).